# Why is it worth studying groupoids if they are so similar to groups?

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, group-actions, groupoids

I know that in the pure algebraic context, connected groupoids are equivalent to groups. Moreover, connected groupoids can be seen as action groupoids. Consequently, any abstract groupoid is essentially a disjoint union of action groupoids.

Therefore, is it not more natural to study group actions than study groupoids? Since group actions seems to have a richer structure than groupoids.

So, why study groupoids?

Does this also hold in a continuous context?

Comment: One might start here https://www.groupoids.org.uk/gpdsweb.html

Comment: Which references this https://mathoverflow.net/questions/40945/compelling-evidence-that-two-basepoints-are-better-than-one/46808#46808